# MongoDb Max Query

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following data in MongoDb:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "name" : "call", "hour": 10, "number" : 14 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "name" : "call", "hour": 11, "number" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "name" : "call", "hour": 12, "number" : 200 }
```

I want to query from the MongoDb to shows that which hour has the most number of calling, so after querying the result will be like this(I want it to show me the whole line):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "name" : "call", "hour": 12, "number" : 200 }
```

I find that MongoDb has its own max() function but it does not work like this. Could anybody tell me how to do this simple query?

Thank you for kij's idea. So if I query like this:

```
db.xxx.find({name:"call"}).sort({number:-1}).limit(1)
```

It gives me the correct result which I want; but it is quite stupid. Is there any other more directly way?

Comment: Just to note - the order of the calls (find, sort, skip and limit) does not effect the execution at all. It's best to order by ease of use - which is find, sort, skip, limit in my opinion. The MongoDB wire protocol shows these are transmitted as properties, and therefore order is not even sent - http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/#wire-op-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
db.collection.find().limit(1).sort( { number: -1 } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you could sort by  desc and take first result. I think it's an alternative if max does not works as expected.
I did not practive since a long time but with something like that maybe:

```
db.collection.sort({'object.number: -1}).limit(1).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

kij's pointed into correct answer I believe. Just add index on your "number" field and queries will be optimized.
The order of sort, limit and find is always the same in MongoDB find queries, no matter how query is written (end paragraph on page's bottom):
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/
Aggregation in MongoDB gives more control on order, sort and limit I think.
Peter